# strpos not working for first string among comma separated strings

Tags: php, strpos

See this [demo](https://3v4l.org/VV04d)

I have two lists of comma separated strings, and want to look for strings and return a message. I noticed that in the particular case that I look for the first string of the first list, it will not find it. If I move that string to another placement, it will. Can't understand why.

```
$dynamic_list = "AZ, CA, CO";
$static_list = "MN,WA,IA";

$search = "AZ";


if ( strpos($dynamic_list . ',' . $static_list, $search) == false && !empty($search) ) { // check string is not empty + that it is not on any of the lists
    echo 'not found: String '.$search.' was not found in lists';
} else {
    echo 'found';
}
```

Comment: you need to update `===` instead of `==`

Comment: Just in addition / as an explanation to the existing answer: `$x == false` will be `true` when `$x` is actually `false`, but also when it is `0`. Since the position of `AZ` in your string is at index `0`, the condition of the `if` is true here. To check for `false` and only `false`, use `===`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note our use of `===`.  Simply `==` would not work as expected because the position of 'A' in 'AZ' is the 0th (first) character. So `===` will do the job
for you here. Let's try with `===`

**See examples here:** https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

**Warning**

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

```
<?php

$dynamic_list = "AZ, CA, CO";
$static_list = "MN,WA,IA";
$search = "AZ";

if (strpos($dynamic_list . ',' . $static_list, $search) === false) {
    echo 'not found: String '.$search.' was not found in lists';
} else {
    echo 'found';
}
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/bo4Yjr

Answer (score 2):

```
    $dynamic_list = "AZ, CA, CO";
    $static_list = "MN,WA,IA";

    $search = "AZ";


    if ( strpos($dynamic_list . ',' . $static_list, $search) === false && !empty($search) ) { // check string is not empty + that it is not on any of the lists
        echo 'not found: String '.$search.' was not found in lists';
    } else {
        echo 'found';
    }
```

add === and then try

Answer (score 1):

> You just need to replace `===` with `==`, So it will check variable type to, here your `strpos()` is returning `0` which will read as false as in your if will get

```
$dynamic_list = "AZ, CA, CO";
$static_list = "MN,WA,IA";
$search = "AZ";
if ( strpos($dynamic_list . ',' . $static_list, $search) === false && !empty($search) ) { 
        echo 'not found: String '.$search.' was not found in lists';
} else {
        echo 'found';
}
```